# How can I mount a remote folder to my local directory

Tags: ubuntu, mount

I am given a guest ssh login (with username and password) to a remote server. 
How can I mount a directory on the remote server locally on my machine?
Both remote server and local machine are running Ubuntu.
And I don't have permission to change configuration on the remote server.

Please let me know if you have any idea.

Thank you.

I tried https://askubuntu.com/questions/46183/how-to-map-a-network-drive

The output of '% smbclient -L //10.22.123.45' is

Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.4.7]

```
    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    print$          Disk      Printer Drivers
    IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (mobmm-ubuntu22 server (Samba, Ubuntu))
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.4.7]

    Server               Comment
    ---------            -------
    MOBMM-UBUNTU16       mobmm-ubuntu16 server (Samba, Ubuntu)
    MOBMM-UBUNTU22       mobmm-ubuntu22 server (Samba, Ubuntu)

    Workgroup            Master
    ---------            -------
    WORKGROUP            MOBMM-UBUNTU16
```

and then I do 'sudo mount -t cifs -o username=guest //10.22.123.45/MOBMM-UBUNTU22 /mnt/mylocaldirectory '

I get this error:

```
Retrying with upper case share name
mount error(6): No such device or address
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I tried another name 'MOBMM-UBUNTU16', same result.

And when I do 'sudo mount -t cifs -o username=guest //10.22.123.45/IPC$ /mnt/mylocaldirectory'

I get

```
mount error(5): Input/output error
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs
```

Comment: Does this help? http://askubuntu.com/questions/46183/how-to-map-a-network-drive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to mount using `sshfs`. Try this from the local machine:

```
sshfs -o idmap=user $USER@1.2.3.4:/remote/path /local/path
```

See [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS) for more information.